# How to replace first word in flutter or dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

for Example:  "This is an Apple" replace "is" to "__",

in java

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {
       String a="This is an Apple";
       String b=a.replaceFirst("\\bis\\b","__");
       System.out.println(b);// This __ an Apple
    }
}
```

but in flutter or dart \\b is not working。

```
void main(){
    String a="This is an Apple";
    String b=a.replaceFirst("\\bis\\b","__");
    print(b);//This is an Apple
}
```

Comment: Maybe the word is "Apple" or "This"?,\\b can match in java , but flutter not.

Answer (score 0):

try with this for single space

```
void main(){
    String a="This is an Apple";
    String b=a.replaceFirst(new RegExp(r"\sis\s")," __ ");
    print(b);//This __ an Apple
}
```

output:
This __ an Apple

Another method:

```
void main(){
    String a="This is an Apple";
    String b=a.replaceFirst(" is "," __ ");
    print(b);//This __ an Apple
}
```

Comment: Maybe the word is "Apple" or "This"?,\\b can match in java , but flutter not.

Comment: In flutter, for single space use `\s`instead of `\b` @DesmondZhou

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use '\\s' instead of '\\b'. See the example below

```
void main() 
{
  final originalString = 'This is an Apple';
  final replacedString = originalString.replaceFirst(RegExp('\\sis\\s'), ' __ ');
  print(replacedString);  // This __ an Apple
}
```

Comment: Maybe the word is "Apple" or "This"?,\\b can match in java , but flutter not.